# How can I find the name of the hotspot connected devices from command line?

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

In my debian machine I have created an hotspot (hostapd) and some devices are connected using Wi-Fi. How can I get the name of the connected devices `ex: xyz iphone, apple tv, john pc` from the command line?

*Note:* Currently I am getting the MAC and the IP addresses using the `arp` command, but not the *device name*.

Answer (score 3):

Quick reminder of the layers involved: LAN and WLAN communicate using MAC addresses (OSI level 2). The ARP protocol tells you which MAC address belongs to which IP address (OSI level 3). Names of machines are handled by DNS. Typically, your home router runs a DNS server, where you either can enter which name belongs to which MAC address, or it automatically uses names if they are provided by DHCP.

So:

1. Get MACs of connected stations using `iw wlan0 station dump`, where `wlan0` is the IF of your hotspot. That's more reliable than the arp cache, because the arp cache may not include *all* connected machines, and it may also include *other* machines on other LANs etc. `arp-scan` is also less reliable, because it will try to get ARP responses over WLAN, but the hotspot already knows exactly *which* machines are connected.
2. For each of those MACs, find the corresponding IP address. The only command line tool I can think of for this is `arping`, but there's probably a better way.
3. For each of the IPs, do a DNS reverse lookup to uour home router, e.g. `host <ip-addr>`.

Yes, it's that difficult, and if you want to do it properly, you can't take shortcuts. There might be some tool which does that for you, but I don't know any, so you'll have to script it.